# elastix Callcenter module Outbound Campaign not working

Tags: asterisk, elastix

I m a newbie in Asterisk and Elastix world.
I have recently configured Elastix for our outbound campaign and its working perfectly . Now I have added Callcenter Module and created an outbound campaign for our sales team. But despite of several tries and browsing the internet have not been successful on making it work.

Steps followed:

-Added Agent with extension having permission of Agent Console.
-Tested Agents with Logging in with Agent Console .
-Created Queue and assigned the static Agents with Pattern A6001,0 . 
-Create outbound Campaign with Callsheet in csv format ( CSV is showing correctly , tested it in the Campaign report it shows the csv phone number values as pending )
After these steps , I'm still not able to get a call initialized from the queue and the extension number just plays the music and waits for the call from the queue but never receives one.

Please help and let me know whether I m missing something here. 
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Call Center ignores all dialplans, including trunk's. 
Make sure that you phone numbers in CSV appear exactly as they should be dialed. Try to set trunk explicitly in the campaign properties (not "by dialplan")

Additionally, make sure the following:
- the numbers in the CSV are in the first column and column's header is "phone" (without quotations)
- CSV separator is strictly commas and encoding is UTF-8 (with BOM)
- if you have non-Latin characters in CSV, all values in such columns should be in quotations (it's OK for Latin characters too) but headers should be without quotations and strictly only in Latin (English) characters
- you choose right queue in the campaign
- agents' numbers in Call Center/Agent Options match their numbers in PBX/queue

Check in Campaign Monitoring that you agents are indicated as "Free" in the status column. Just pending calls without dealing them most likely means that you have no available agents assigned for this campaign. This sometime happens, nothing helps but creating new queue and reboot.